# PHP MySQL: Delete row if its not present in API data

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json, wordpress

I am getting data from API and adding it to a table.
we have a status to control the data visible on website
if Status = available show on web or if Status = Expired remove it from website

While inserting the data from API, I am running update and insert query.

`$final_data = $response->Results;` - //Data From API JSON converted to Array

and checking if data is already their in table **Update**
if data is not their **Insert**

```
if(is_array($final_data)) {
    foreach ($final_data as $row) {
        $id = $row->id
        $data1 = $row->data1;
        $data2 = $row->data2;
        $data3 = $row->data3;
    }

    global $wpdb;

    // Insert Data if not exists
    $updateJobsDatabase_mainquery = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT id  FROM ".$table_name." WHERE id = ".$id."");

    if (count($updateJobsDatabase_mainquery) > 0) { 
        // Update query excluding id
    } else {
        // Insert query including id
    }
}
```

But by this logic when status changes to expired for one of the data row in API.
it still stays in database.

I want to remove that row from local table.
So what will be a proper way to remove the rows which are not falling in the **If-Else** statements. i.e. extra rows which are not in API data but present in local database.

I am thinking `if (count($updateJobsDatabase_mainquery) = 0)` will return the data which does not match the id of API data. and to remove it using

`$deleteIfStatus = $wpdb->query('DELETE FROM '.$table_name_temp.' WHERE id = what? ');`

but then again what should I add in where clause? if this logic is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your code correctly you should be able to use (assuming `id` is numeric)

```
$deleteIfStatus = $wpdb->query('DELETE FROM '.$table_name_temp.' WHERE id NOT IN (' . implode(',', array_map(function ($v) { return $v->code; }, $updateJobsDatabase_mainquery)) . ')');
```

If `id` is not numeric, use

```
$deleteIfStatus = $wpdb->query('DELETE FROM '.$table_name_temp.' WHERE id NOT IN (\'' . implode("','", array_map(function ($v) { return $v->code; }, $updateJobsDatabase_mainquery)) . '\')');
```

Comment: Yes it is numeric, Tried both without if statement, having error `Catchable fatal error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string`

Comment: I've obviously misinterpreted the contents of `$updateJobsDatabase_mainquery`. What is in it?

Comment: it contains all records from local table `$updateJobsDatabase_mainquery = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT id  FROM ".$table_name." WHERE id = ".$id."");`

Comment: Sorry I meant what is the data format? it seems to be an array of objects based on the error you got?

Comment: One array for each loop `Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [PositionId] => 50982 [JobTitle] => 3rd Shift Shipping and Receiving Supervisor ) )`

Comment: For this query `"SELECT id FROM ".$table_name." WHERE id = ".$id.""` it should be an array of `stdClass Object ( [id] => 50982 )`?

Comment: I've updated my answer based on the assumption that `$updateJobsDatabase_mainquery` is an array of objects like `stdClass Object ( [id] => 50982 )`. Can you give that a try?

Comment: Yes after getting idea from your answer, modified function a bit and its working. will update the solution in question itself.

Comment: Added final working solution in Solution section of question

Answer (score 1):

**Final Solution as recommended by Nick - Outside for each loop**

```
$deleteFromDatabase_mainquery = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT PositionId  FROM `".$table_name_temp."`");

$deleteFromDatabase_tmparr1 = array();
$deleteFromDatabase_tmparr2 = array();

foreach ($deleteFromDatabase_mainquery as $row) { // Push local table id's in empty array
    array_push($deleteFromDatabase_tmparr1, $row->PositionId);
}
foreach ($final_data as $row) { // Push API data id's in empty array
    array_push($deleteFromDatabase_tmparr2, $row->PositionId);
}
// Add a joint array excluding excess records.
$deleteFromDatabase_finalqr = array_intersect($deleteFromDatabase_tmparr2,$deleteFromDatabase_tmparr1);

// Delete data from live table where ids are not present in new joint array
$deleteIfStatus = $wpdb->query("DELETE FROM ".$table_name." WHERE PositionId NOT IN ('" . implode( "', '" , $deleteFromDatabase_finalqr ) . "' )");
```