# Compare JSON against MySQL database for removed records

Tags: php, mysql, json

I’ve set up a JSON parser that adds events to a MySQL database using PHP. All events in the JSON file has an ID that I check to see if it already exists in the database and if so, only updates certain data. And if the event doesn’t exist, it adds it to the database.

All of that works well but one issue is that I don’t know if there are events that have been deleted from the JSON file but have been imported to the database previously. The import runs once a week so last week an event could have been added that now has been cancelled so I would like to deactivate these events (there's a Status flag in the database).

I’ve tried setting up a separate query for this ($check_removed) but I can’t get it to work, it doesn't seem to do anything. To the query I also added a check to only look for upcoming events since events that are older than today aren't relevant.

This is my code, a bit simplified:

```
$filename = "events.json";
$data = file_get_contents($filename);
$array = json_decode($data, true);

foreach ($array as $row) {
 $id = $row["id"];
 $title = $row["title"];
 $date = $row["date"];

 // Get current date for comparison of removed records
 $today = date("Y-m-d");

 $check = mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT * FROM `events` WHERE `ID` = '".$id."'"); 
 $check_removed = mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT * FROM `events` WHERE `date` >= '".$today."' AND `ID` != '".$id."'");  

 if(mysqli_num_rows($check_removed)==1) {
  // Upcoming event found in database but not in JSON (doesn't work)
 } elseif(mysqli_num_rows($check)==1) {
  // Existing ID matches, only update event (this works)
 } else {
  // No existing ID matches, add new event (this works)
 }
}
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Are you getting any error? What is not working?

Comment: No errors in PHP or SQL. It just seems to skip the first IF query.

Comment: What do echo mysqli_num_rows($check_removed) give you? And try to change "SELECT * FROM `events` WHERE `ID` = '".$id."'" to "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `events` WHERE `ID` = '".$id."'" and echo the result

Comment: Your logic is wrong: The second query gets all future events minus the one with the current id. If you handle the dates correctly. Instead, you should add all id's to an array and do an sql check with `NOT IN(...)` after the loop.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for pushing me in the right direction! It helped me find [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52732024/6942456) that I could modify to make it work.

```
$FutureRecords = mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT `ID` FROM `events` WHERE `date` >= '".$today."'");

$FutureRecords_TempArray1 = array();
$FutureRecords_TempArray2 = array();

foreach ($FutureRecords as $row) { // Push local table id's in empty array
    array_push($FutureRecords_TempArray1, $row["ID"]);
}
foreach ($array as $row) { // Push JSON data id's in empty array
    array_push($FutureRecords_TempArray2, $row["ID"]);
}
// Add a joint array excluding excess records.
$FutureRecords_Query = array_intersect($FutureRecords_TempArray2,$FutureRecords_TempArray1);

// Update data in live table where ids are not present in new joint array
$DeactivateRemovedRecords = mysqli_query($connect,"UPDATE `events` SET `Active` = 0 WHERE `Start` >= '".$today."' AND `ID ` NOT IN ('" . implode( "', '" , $FutureRecords_Query ) . "' )");
```